# stuck in a function because of an infinite loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void dossier (FILE*f,FILE*f2)
{
    char k ;

    k=fgetc(f) ;
    fputc(k,f2) ;
    printf("here%c",k) ;

    while ( k!='\\')
    {
        k=fgetc(f);
        fputc(k,f2);
    }
}

void dossierp(FILE*f,FILE*f2)
{
    char ch [1000] ;
    do
    {
        dossier(f,f2) ;
    }
    while (fgets(ch,1000,f) !=NULL) ;
}

int main()
{

    FILE*f=NULL ;
    FILE*f2=NULL ;
    f = fopen("text.txt","r+") ;
    f2= fopen("t.txt","r+") ;
    dossierp(f,f2);
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

The file `f` contains lines. Every line is in this form "`(text)\text2)\...\`". The file `f2` is empty, the function `dossier` works, but `dossierp` doesn't work because it has an infinite loop. Why?

Comment: first of all: ALWAYS check the result of fopen()!

Comment: Maybe `EOF` is causing the problem. BTW, `k` should be of type `int`, not `char`. Try `while ( k!='\\' && k!=EOF)`.

Comment: thank you @CoolGuy that was the solution

Comment: this echos each line of the file until a '\' is encountered, then consumes the rest of the (up to 1000 characters) with no further processing.  There is no guarantee that 1000 characters was enough.  suggest using getline() rather than fgets() (and of course, free'ing the resultant value from getline.

Comment: for file pointer 'f2', why is the file being opened with 'r+'  rather than either 'w' or 'a'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't handle `EOF` in `dossier`. So, the infinite loop would be in the `dossier` function in certain cases, not in the `dossierp` function.

And note that `getc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. `char` cannot represent `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
The function has a problem because 

when dossierp calls dossier 
then reads the rest of the line, the EOF indication is NOT set

the dossirp then jumps to the top of the loop 
and calls dossier
but the fgetc results are not being checked for EOF
so they keep on trying to read characters, and always failing
so that is where the infinite loop is at.

suggest adding a check of the results of each call to fgetc 
for EOF and exiting the function when EOF is encountered,
returning an indication to dossierp that EOF was encountered
so dossierp can exit its loop and exit the function.

Note: reading the last line (or last character) of a file
      does not set EOF.
      Rather trying to read past the last line (or last char)
      of a file sets EOF.

 Note: EOF is an integer, so the fgetc() return variables must
       be int, not char

 a few minutes with a debugger and attention to what 
 each function returns when EOF is encountered
 (and/or an error is encountered)
 would have made finding the root of this problem very easy.
```